# Why is listbox not showing new added items by thread in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, listbox, listboxitem

I'm new to ASP.NET and I'm trying to make a chat application on web.
I used System.Net.Sockets for communication between server and client. With the current version of application I can send data from client to server, and send data from server to client. Client gets the data with a thread and thread has a loop in it to get the data continuously. The problem is I get the data from server to client and it is being added to the listbox items but its not showing the data in the listbox. I am thinking that the problem is because of using thread or loop.

Code of Client:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Client_s__Web_2
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        static int port = 13000;
        static string IpaAddress = "127.0.0.1";
        static Socket ClientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        static IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IpaAddress), port);
        static string client_ismi = "";
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClientSocket.Connect(ep);
            ListBox1.Items.Add("Client is connected.");
            byte[] isim = new byte[1024];
            int size = ClientSocket.Receive(isim);
            client_ismi = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(isim, 0, size);
            Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx");
            ListBox1.Items.Add("The name that server has given: " + client_ismi);
            System.Windows.Forms.Form.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;

            ThreadStart st = new ThreadStart(get_data);
            Thread thread = new Thread(st);
            thread.Start();
        }
        public void get_data()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                byte[] MsgFromServer = new byte[1024];
                int size1 = ClientSocket.Receive(MsgFromServer);
                ListBox1.Items.Add("Server: " + System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(MsgFromServer, 0, size1));
            }
        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string messageFromClient = null;
            messageFromClient = client_ismi + ": " + TextBox1.Text;
            TextBox1.Text = "";
           ClientSocket.Send(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messageFromClient), 0, messageFromClient.Length, SocketFlags.None);
        }
    }
}
```

Code of Clients Aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Client_s__Web_2.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton = "Button2">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Start" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Width ="700px" Height="500px"></asp:ListBox>
            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width ="700px" Height="50px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Send" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Refresh" OnClick="Button3_Click" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </asp:Panel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code of Server

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace Main_Server
{
    class Program
    {

        static List<string> names = new List<string>();
        static List<Socket> clients = new List<Socket>();
        static Program p = new Program();
        static int counter = 0;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int port = 13000;
            string IpAddress = "127.0.0.1";
            Socket ServerListener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IpAddress), port);
            ServerListener.Bind(ep);
            ServerListener.Listen(100);
            Console.WriteLine("Server is listening");
            Socket ClientSocket = default(Socket);


            while(true)
            {
                counter++;
                ClientSocket = ServerListener.Accept();
                clients.Add(ClientSocket);

                string msgstr = "Guest_" + Convert.ToString(counter);
                names.Add(msgstr);
                byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msgstr);
                int size = msg.Length;
                ClientSocket.Send(msg, 0, size, SocketFlags.None);
                Console.WriteLine(msgstr + " has connected");
                Thread UserThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => p.User(counter - 2, msgstr)));
                UserThread.Start();
            }
        }
        public void User(int bulunan_client,string username)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                byte[] msg = new byte[1024];
                int size = clients[bulunan_client].Receive(msg);
                try
                {
                    if (System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(msg, 0, size).Substring(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(msg, 0, size).Length - 10) == "disconnect")
                    {
                        names.Remove(names[bulunan_client]);
                        clients.Remove(clients[bulunan_client]);
                        Console.WriteLine(username + " has disconnected.");
                        counter--;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(msg, 0, size).Substring(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(msg, 0, size).Length - 7) == "connect")
                    {
                        string sending_names = "";


                        for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
                        {
                            sending_names += (names[i] + " ");
                        }
                        clients[bulunan_client].Send(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sending_names), 0, (System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sending_names)).Length, SocketFlags.None);



                        continue;
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    break;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(msg,0,size));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: When i send "connect" from client i should be getting names of the connected clients. I get them to the listbox items but they are not showing. I did this program with windows form application and i didnt have any problems with listbox at all.

Thank you guys for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

Τhe problem here is that you start a thread and return...in a console this have a point to not block the ui, but in a web application you can't do the same.

So here in this lines, the program returns and render the page.

```
 ThreadStart st = new ThreadStart(get_data);
 Thread thread = new Thread(st);
 thread.Start();
```

Later and if the thread call the `get_data` there is no page to render anything any more...

So the solution is to remove the thread - just include the function of the thread to fill the data.

I also notice on the code this `while (true)` that is block in a dead loop as it is. Fix this also.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) But there is something i need to understand. How can I be able to get data from server anytime if I dont use thread? It needs to get the data continously. Or I just couldnt understand what you meant :) And is there any way to refresh the listbox from thread?

Comment: @AteşArkuran The calling of the page its a thread by him self. Its not like the desktop programming that the program is wait and the UI is stack on one thread and you need to open a second one... On one call the user just wait the results, the server is running your code, nothing stop here like desktop programs. From the other hand on the web programming to continuously refress of the any drop down control you need to use other design, eg the use of an ajax call. But first make this work with out a thread... then you see if you need one...